# Can a Laravel Policy tell the user/caller why it has failed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel policies are formulated as can() statements that return true or false. However, if we are not allowed an action, we are never given a reason why (since the method can only return true or false). All we can tell the user is that they cannot perform this action - not why they cannot.

Is there an established way of making a Laravel policy inform the caller why it has failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to throw for example:

```
 Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException('Message why fails');
```

in the place where policy fails. If you have this exception defined in `App\Exceptions\Handler` then it will response the request with the given message through the `AuthorizationException`.

Comment: If I do something like this, will I still be able to do something like Gate::check() without having to wrap it in a try-catch?

EDIT: I looked at the definition of Gate::check() and it does in fact wrap its call in a try-catch, but it only catches AuthorizationExceptions, so any exception you throw in a policy should be an AuthorizationException (or inherited from it). I'll mark your answer as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every policy in Laravel uses `Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization` trait by default.

This trait contains useful method `deny`. When you want to give a reason why user action failed - you can simply call `$this->deny('Your reason')` right inside policy.

Under the hood, it throws `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`, so accepted answer is not wrong anyway.

If for some reason your are not OK with `AuthorizationException`, you can simply throw `AnyCustomException`.